# Cannot Install Ubuntu - dump_stack+0x45 (?)

Tags: system-installation

I don't understand Linux and Debian very well, I'm not much of a geek, but I support open source, so I wanted to use Ubuntu. I ran the installation, and came with an error talking about a callback and dump_stack+0x45, which I don't understand. Here was the error:

```
Hardware name: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC. K30AD_M31AD_M51AD/K30AD_M31AD_M51AD, BIOS 0402 11/ ...
0000000000000009 ffff8803036f9e78 ffffffff8171bcb4 0000000000000000
ffff8803036f9eb0 ffffffff810676cd ffff88031ed8e600 ff00000000000001
0000000000000001 000000000240fb70 0000000002f0fda0 ffff8803036f9ec0
Call Trace:
dump_stack+0x45/0x56
dequeue_task_idle+0x30/0x90
dequeue_task+0x5a/0x80
deactivate_task+0x23/0x30
__schedule+0x560/0x7d0
```

There is more, see these pictures:

http://postimg.org/image/nq9cmgmgf/

http://postimg.org/image/59exvn6i7/

Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS 64-bit

Answer (score 0):

Do you see the Grub2 boot menu or does it crash without showing it?

This is some newer Intel CPU and Nvidia card I assume.
In my case, I was able to boot Ubuntu Live CD/USB and install it. But on restart I would get stuck on black screen seeing same as you.

I had this issue when installing and NOT clicking on "Download updates while installing". Also check your BIOS /UEFI settings, if the machine is new, maybe it has UEFI Bios. Disable "Secure Boot" and set the boot mode to "Legacy".

After I changed this and reinstalled Ubuntu clean, the problem was solved.

Try it and report ;)

[image]